# Assigning values to 2d array with list of coordinates and time series without for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have data with four attributes. Two are coordinates `xs` and `ys`; the other two are timestamps `ts` and polarity `ps`.
I need to set the value of an image at each position `(x,y)` with the newest polarity. The xs and ys are not unique.

I can do it with for-loop as shown below and I need a vectorized way:

```py
import numpy as np

color_p = (0, 0, 255)
color_n = (255, 0, 0)
H, W = 128, 128
n_p = 100

xs, ys = np.random.randint(0, W, n_p), np.random.randint(0, H, n_p)
ts = np.random.rand(n_p)
ts.sort()
ps = np.random.randint(0, 2, n_p)

img = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(n_p):
    x, y, p = xs[i], ys[i], ps[i]
    img[y, x] = color_p if p > 0 else color_n
```

Comment: Are you sure you want random integers for `xs` and `ys`? They will not be unique and will result in overwriting when doing the `for` loop.

Comment: Are the `(x,y)` coordinates all guaranteed to be unique or did you say "newest polarity" because there can be repeats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that if you have duplicate `(x,y)` coordinates, the later ones will overwrite the earlier values. So, what you can do is find the unique coordinates in reverse order and use those to set the values.

```py
points = np.vstack((xs, ys))

# unique indices are taken from the end of the array, so they need to be
# recalculated to be based off the front of the array
unique_indices = np.unique(points[:,::-1], axis=1, return_index=True)[1]
unique_indices = n_p - unique_indices - 1
x_unique, y_unique = points[:,unique_indices]
img2 = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

cond = ps[unique_indices] > 0
img2[y_unique[cond], x_unique[cond]] = color_p
img2[y_unique[~cond], x_unique[~cond]] = color_n
```

I tested this code with `n_p = 1000` to ensure there were duplicates and verified the results were correct using `(img == img2).all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
img2 = np.zeros((H, W, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
m = ps > 0
img2[ys[m], xs[m]] = color_p
img2[ys[~m], xs[~m]] = color_n
```

Check:

```
>>> np.all(img == img2)
True
```

Comment: Check your solution when `n_p = 1000` to ensure there are duplicate `(x,y)` coordinates. I don't think it works correctly in that case.

Comment: Why do you think there may be duplicates? Isn't this a toy example?

Comment: Based on how OP said "newest polarity" rather than just polarity. That seems to tell me that the data will be generated over time and that there might not be anything preventing coordinates from being chosen more than once. But OP should clarify. If the points are unique, then your answer is the way to go.

Comment: there will be duplicates as the time goes on.